# iOS swift memory issue during a while-loop inside a closure: AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, memory, swift2, avassetwriter

My app is for making a video file from many images that are produced by code.

When my code has finished making an image and put it in myImage, it toggles isImageReady to 'true'. And when self.i is set(or changed),by Property Observer,it starts making another image. and finally the self.iReset is set to 'true' when there's no more image to be produced.

but the app is terminated due to memory issue during the while-loop. I have commented out the if-statement that actually assembles video frames. and it still has a memory issue. so I think the poblem lives during the while-loop inside requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock closure.

I have no idea how to solve the problem. please help me.

```
    if videoWriter.startWriting() {
        videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
        assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)

        let media_queue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", nil)
        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(media_queue, usingBlock: { () -> Void in
            let fps: Int32 = 30
            let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, fps)
            var lastFrameTime:CMTime = CMTime()
            var presentationTime:CMTime = CMTime()

            while (self.iReset != true) {
                if videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData && self.isImageReady {
                    lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(self.i), fps)
                    presentationTime = self.i == 1 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)

                    //commented out for tracking
                    /* if !self.appendPixelBufferForImage(self.myImage, pixelBufferAdaptor: pixelBufferAdaptor, presentationTime: presentationTime) {
                    error = NSError(
                    domain: kErrorDomain,
                    code: kFailedToAppendPixelBufferError,
                    userInfo: [
                    "description": "AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter failed to append pixel buffer",
                    "rawError": videoWriter.error ?? "(none)"])
                    break
                    } */

                    self.isImageReady = false
                    self.i++
                }// if ..&&..
            } //while loop ends


            // Finish writing
            videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Finished Making a Movie !!")
                    success(videoOutputURL)
                }
                self.videoWriter = nil
            }
        }) // requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue ends
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but I had a similar issue to this (images in a loop) which caused me a major headache. My solution was to put an autoreleasepool within the loop which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per @C. Carter has suggested you can use `autoreleasepool` to free the used memory like below:

```
autoreleasepool {
  /* your code */ 
}
```

Other than that here is a code from which I am making movie using `UIImages` and `Audio` which works perfectly fine.

```
func build(chosenPhotos: [UIImage], audioURL: NSURL, completion: (NSURL) -> ()) {
        showLoadingIndicator(appDel.window!.rootViewController!.view)
        let outputSize = CGSizeMake(640, 480)
        var choosenPhotos = chosenPhotos
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first else {
            fatalError("documentDir Error")
        }

    let videoOutputURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("OutputVideo.mp4")
    print("Video Output URL \(videoOutputURL)")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(videoOutputURL.path!) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(videoOutputURL.path!)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
        }
    }

    guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: videoOutputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4) else {
        fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
    }

    let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.height))]

    guard videoWriter.canApplyOutputSettings(outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
        fatalError("Negative : Can't apply the Output settings...")
    }

    let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB), kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.width)), kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.height))]
    let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

    if videoWriter.canAddInput(videoWriterInput) {
        videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)
    }

    if videoWriter.startWriting() {
        videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
        assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)

        let media_queue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", nil)

        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(media_queue, usingBlock: { () -> Void in
            let fps: Int32 = 1
            let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, fps)

            var frameCount: Int64 = 0
            var appendSucceeded = true
            while (!choosenPhotos.isEmpty) {
                if (videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                    let nextPhoto = choosenPhotos.removeAtIndex(0)
                    let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount, fps)
                    let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)

                    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
                    let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)

                    if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer where status == 0 {
                        let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer

                        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

                        let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, Int(outputSize.width), Int(outputSize.height), 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), rgbColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

                        CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(outputSize.width), CGFloat(outputSize.height)))

                        let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(outputSize.width) / nextPhoto.size.width
                        let verticalRatio = CGFloat(outputSize.height) / nextPhoto.size.height
                        //aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
                        let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit

                        let newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(nextPhoto.size.width * aspectRatio, nextPhoto.size.height * aspectRatio)

                        let x = newSize.width < outputSize.width ? (outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                        let y = newSize.height < outputSize.height ? (outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

                        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(x, y, newSize.width, newSize.height), nextPhoto.CGImage)

                        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

                        appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
                    } else {
                        print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                        appendSucceeded = false
                    }
                }
                if !appendSucceeded {
                    break
                }
                frameCount += 1
            }
            videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
                print("FINISHED!!!!!")
                self.compileToMakeMovie(videoOutputURL, audioOutPutURL: audioURL, completion: { url in
                    completion(url)
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

func compileToMakeMovie(videoOutputURL: NSURL, audioOutPutURL: NSURL, completion: (NSURL) -> ()){

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first else {
        fatalError("documentDir Error")
    }

    let actualVideoURl = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("OutputVideoMusic.mp4")
    print("Video Output URL \(actualVideoURl)")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(actualVideoURl.path!) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(actualVideoURl.path!)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
        }
    }

    let nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoOutputURL)
    let video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration)
    let a_compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    try! a_compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(video_timeRange, ofTrack: videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], atTime: nextClipStartTime)

    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioOutPutURL)
    let audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAsset.duration)
    let b_compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    do {
        try b_compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audio_timeRange, ofTrack: audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0], atTime: nextClipStartTime)
    }catch _ {}


    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = "com.apple.quicktime-movie"
    assetExport?.outputURL = actualVideoURl
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        completion(actualVideoURl)
    })
}
```

Let me know, if you're still facing the issue.